# Scatterplot: Show missing factor level(s) in legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a scatterplot + legend, using a grouping variable ("category") in the example below. How can I force all factor levels (i.e., `LETTERS[1:5]` below) , even if missing in the actual data, to show up in the legend (to stress their absence!):

```
dat <- data.frame(V1 = sample(seq(1:10), 10),
              V2 = sample(seq(1:10), 10),
              category = factor(sample(LETTERS[1:4], 10, replace=TRUE),
                  LETTERS[1:5]))

ggplot(dat, aes(x=V1, y=V2)) +
    geom_point(aes(size=category), shape=1)
```

In my actual script, I use `scale_size_discrete()` to change the legend labels etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `scale_size_discrete()` and add argument `drop=FALSE` to show all levels.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=V1, y=V2)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=category), shape=1)+
  scale_size_discrete(drop=FALSE)
```